# WebClient not emitting a response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux

I just recently came across an issue that leaves me puzzled. I'm happy about every advice you can give, even if it's about how to get more insights (i.e. logging).

I am using spring boot 2.0.0M1 (as generated from start.spring.io) with the reactive (netty backed) `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient`.

When calling an old, non-reactive service that just returns a JSON object, the WebClient does not emit any event, even though the called service is fully responsive (compare log).

`2017-05-29 17:33:30,016 | reactor-http-nio-2 | INFO  | | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxOnAssembly.OnAssemblySubscriber)                                                                                          | myLogClass:145                       | 
2017-05-29 17:33:30,016 | reactor-http-nio-2 | INFO  | | request(unbounded)                                                                                                                                   | myLogClass:145                       | 
2017-05-29 17:33:30,016 | reactor-http-nio-2 | DEBUG | | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxOnAssembly.OnAssemblySubscriber)                                                                                          | client:125                          | 
2017-05-29 17:33:30,016 | reactor-http-nio-2 | DEBUG | | request(unbounded)                                                                                                                                   | client:125                          |`

When debugging this issue, I figured something strange that leaves me thinking that I'm simply using this implementation in a wrong way: I saw an URL from another service (that I called earlier) in nettys pool/channel handling (will add the class I found it in later).

Other observations:

- when I leave the other WebClient call out of the picture, the problematic call works
- the called services are behind a gateway, so they (might) have the same IP but different URI

So my seemingly unlikely ideas so far:

- netty channel/pool handling somehow screws my urls up
- WebClient shouldn't be used with different URIs
- there is a f'up with URI/IP mapping on the way back from netty to the subscribers

As I said in the beginning: I am thankful for every help and of course I will add any information you request to reproduce this bugger.
Any pointer on how to maybe write a test for this is welcome as well!

Starting with information: this is how I use the WebClient as a minimum sample (I know - I am not planning on using it in a blocking way..)

```
return WebClient.create(serviceUri)
        .put()
        .uri("/mypath/" + id)
        .body(fromObject(request))
        .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .header(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, createCookie())
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Response.class)
        .log("com.mypackage.myLogClass", Level.ALL)
        .block();
```

Comment: You've described what you think is going on but we can't even try to reproduce the issue, without: having the code you're using (you're mentioning 2 WebClient instances, I only see one), how you're triggering the use case, what you're expecting, what you're getting instead, etc.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for answering even though my question is incomplete. I will try to add more information asap.

Comment: Hi, I'm also new to reactive prog but are you not supposed to call .exchange() when doing the request ?

Comment: retrieve() in this case should be a shortcut and work :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reactive WebClient not emitting a response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930448/reactive-webclient-not-emitting-a-response)