# WebClient Spring 5 IllegalStateException

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I am receiving a MonoError caused by an IllegalStateException with the cause 'The underlying HTTP client completed without emitting a response.'.

NetworkList is a class contains lists of a network topology and has a setList which is called from within the method convertJsonToPojo.

client is a WebClient (spring-webflux) in Spring 5 (5.0.4.RELEASE) using reactor-netty (0.7.5.RELEASE).

The following snippet shows how I am using WebClient to make asynchronous calls to type = BOARDS, CARDS, PORTS, ROUTERS, etc where the network name is passed in as projectName and the topology type is passed in as type.

```
NetworkList netList = new NetworkList();    
client.get().uri("/{project}/{type}",projectName,type).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).subscribe(json -> this.convertJsonToPojo(Type.BOARD, json, netList));
```

The rest service I am hitting against is a singular service which returns json representing the components asked for.

This seems similar to [Reactive WebClient Not Emitting A Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44930448/reactive-webclient-not-emitting-a-response) but a response within points to the following reactor-netty issue [Issue 138](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/138).  That issue indicates fixed as of 0.6.6.RELEASE.

So my question is am I using WebClient wrong unknowingly or should I submit this as an unfixed bug?  I am fairly new to Spring 5 and the Reactive library so do not want to naively submit a bug.

Thank you for your time in advance!

PS - I have this working with RestTemplate and CompletableFuture so no need to offer that suggestion as an alternative.  My tasking is to begin the migration to a reactive architecture.  Thank you!

UPDATE - I believe I understand now what is going on but would like a confirmation from someone.  The rest service I am hitting against is a traditional one and not a Reactive Stream.  Thus, there are no 'stage' updates being shared during the call.  .subscribe() is expecting a reactive stream and thus never received the complete stage.  replacing .subscribe() with .block() forced a completion and the code works now.  So my learning from this is that when dealing with traditional rest services a block is required.  Can someone confirm that please?  Thank you!

Comment: '_So my learning from this is that when dealing with traditional rest services a block is required._' That's not true. Is it possible to share your code? I do not see any obvious error in that two lines.

Comment: @Yossarian, tyvm for replying!!  That is the only code that is using web client and i have tried splitting it up but the basic chaining is the same, any general thoughts as to why this might be occurring?  I am planning to take a Spring Reactive Programming online course so I should get better at this in the near future.  Thanks so much again for replying, too often I will post something and then ..... crickets.  Take care!